# Iterating over nested json array with angular

Tags: json, angularjs

I'm using angular to fetch data from a web service, the data is in JSON format :

```
    {
    "items": [{
        "id": 2,
        "catId": 1,
        "content": "ddddddddddddddddd",
        "type": 0,
        "comments": [{
            "id": 0,
            "postId": 0,
            "userId": 0,
            "content": "nincompoop",
            "ptime": "2015"
        }, {
            "id": 0,
            "postId": 0,
            "userId": 0,
            "content": "lol",
            "ptime": "2015"
        }],
        "Likes": []
    }, {
        "id": -1,
        "catId": 1,
        "content": "first post",
        "type": 0,
        "comments": [{
            "id": 1,
            "postId": 0,
            "userId": 0,
            "content": "first Comment",
            "ptime": "2015"
        }],
        "Likes": [{
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Rawhi"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Also the user ID is stored in a javascript parameter, How can I iterate over the 'item.likes' for each post and determine if the user Id is existing ? thank you

Comment: use `javascript` for it or you want to use in `template` use `ng-Repeat`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your JSON is in a variable called `rawhi`:

```
angular.forEach(rawhi, function (item, key){
    angular.forEach(item, function(comment, index){
        comment.userId //you can check if this exists
        //iterate over the likes array:
        angular.forEach(comment.Likes, function (like, i){
            like //you can do whatever you want to do with this
        });
    });
});
```

Basically, you can use nested [`foreach`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) loops to iterate through the arrays in your JSON.

Answer (score 0):

`forEach.item.Likes(function(prop){ alert(prop) });`

or while inside of your angular controllers view you can use the ngRepeat directive to iterate through this however you will need to clean up that object before either of these will work. Also take the curse word out of your code!